# Question about sum of functions approaching one sided limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Ok so I have been trying to do some calculus and I have stumbled across problem.I ended up trying to prove some things and this is how I went about doing that.I will need you to point out my mistakes if any exist,since I am very new to subject of calculus

Hypothesis:

If:
 $$\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = l$$ $$\lim_{x \to a^+} g(x) = m$$

then $$ \lim_{ x \to a^+}(f+g)(x) = l+m $$

Here is how I tried to prove it:

First lemma:

If: 
$$|x-x_0|<\frac\epsilon2 $$
$$|y-y_0|<\frac\epsilon2 $$

then:

$$|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|< \epsilon$$

Proof of First lemma:
$$|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)| = |(x-x_0) + (y-y_0)| \le |x-x_0| + |y-y_0| < \frac\epsilon2 + \frac\epsilon2 = \epsilon $$

From there I have went by definition of one sided limit and used this lemma in following manner:

$$ a<x<a + \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - l| < \frac\epsilon2  $$ 
$$ a<x<a + \delta_2 \implies |g(x) - m| < \frac\epsilon2  $$

thus using First lemma:

$$ a<x< min(a+\delta_1 , a+\delta_2) \implies |(f+g)(x) - (l+m) |<\epsilon $$

which implies that $$lim_{x \to a^+} (f+g)(x) = l+m $$ and exists.

Comment: Look OK. You might want to explain more precisely that $\epsilon$ is first chosen arbitrarily, then $\delta_1,\delta_2$ are determined based on that $\epsilon$, and finally $\delta$ is computed from $\delta_1,\delta_2$. With $\epsilon$-$\delta$-criterion, you always have to be carefull about what depends on what - in this case, $\delta$ on $\epsilon$, via $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$.

Comment: I wanted to make this post as short as possible,so I didnt explain all details.But would you say that this proof is correct?

Comment: Well, it's not wrong. I personally feel that for easy proofs like this one, which are usually done to get accustomed to working with these kinds of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments, it makes sense to spell out the dependencies very clearly. I'd phrase the proof as: Pick an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Then due to ... there are $\delta_1,\delta_2$ satisfying ... Thus, for $\delta := \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ it holds that $|(f+g)(x) - (l+m)| < \epsilon$. Which proves that $\lim \,\ldots = l+m$.

Comment: I actually did that multiple times in my head,then written it down in my notebook,I understand what you are talking about and I feel that your advice is good.

Comment: If you post such a version of your proof as an answer to your own question, other users of this site might benefit, plus you get to accept your own answer.

Comment: I did not know that.I will do that.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is true because :

$$ \lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = l$$
$$ \lim_{x \to a^+} g(x) = m$$

exist.Now let $\epsilon > 0 \implies \frac\epsilon2 >0  $

Next by definition of limit we have some $\delta_1>0$ and $ \delta_2 >0$ which depend on $\frac\epsilon2$ .

Since these two limits exist we can conclude from definition of limit that:

$$ a<x<a+\delta_1 \implies |f(x) -l | < \frac\epsilon2$$
$$ a<x<a+\delta_2 \implies |g(x) -m | < \frac\epsilon2$$

From that we can conclude by First lemma that:

$$ a

From which we can conclude that $\lim_{x \to a^+} (f+g)(x)$ exists and equals + l+m

Also please note that x has to be less than $ a+min(\delta_1 , \delta_2) $ because x has to be less than both $a+\delta_1$ and $a+\delta_2$ .If it were not less than both then one of functions, f or g, might be larger then expected and their sum minus limit values might not be less than epsilon